Nothing displayed at modern dropdown control in PowerApps
I'm new to PowerApps and I need some help.
I have a SharePoint list called "PC_Repair" with a column named "Status"(type:single text). The status can be either "complete" or "awaiting".
I created a modern dropdown control in PowerApps. When I set the "Items" property to "PC_Repair", the dropdown displays all the status values correctly. However, when I change the "Items" property from "PC_Repair" to "Distinct(PC_Repair, Status)", the dropdown shows two blank rows and no values. The row count is correct, though. it looks like this.
enter image description here
But, I delete this dropdown, input another new dropdown control, and set the "Items" to "Distinct(PC_Repair, Status)". it works.
Could it be caused by the page not refreshing in time? I noticed that even if I changed the "Items" property to ["test1", "test2"], the data source in the right-hand properties pane is still showing "PC_Repair".
Can you please explain why this is happening? and how to solve this issue?
When I use the classic dropdown control, it works fine. don't know why it doesn't work with Mordern control.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I encountered the same thing.
You should try checking the “Fields” property of the dropdown to make sure it is connected to the right field/table column, based on your dropdown's data source such as an Excel table.

